# I am working on text analytics. Please suggest how to proceed with UIMA?

Tags: analytics, text-analysis

I download UIMA for ubuntu 12.4 and perform tokenization. Now I want to preform lemmatisation on some text using UIMA.  Please suggest proper approach.

Comment: Go through this link <br>[Apache UIMA - Getting Started: Why Apache UIMA](https://uima.apache.org/doc-uima-why.html)